# Storyboard Scrollview with StackView inside not scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I know similar questions were asked before but all of them do it programatically and I'm trying to do this in the storyboard.

I have a scroll view with top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints, with a view inside it that is pinned to all edges of the scroll view and has equal width and height @250. Inside that I have a stack view with 6 other views that will change their height dynamically based on how much text each label gets. And it all works fine except for the fact that it doesn't scroll even when content overflows.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a look at the storyboard:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the inner view height which  =  250 , and pin the stackView to all it's edges

[image]

Comment: That then says ScrollView needs constraints for Y position or height. Or did you mean change the priority of the height from 250 to 1000?

Comment: you need to give a static height for each view inside the stackview

Comment: Ah, but that's not going to work, I need the height of those to adjust based on how much text they have inside. Is there a way to do that and keep the scrolling? It's worth noting that this works as is (with variable height for the views) if I centre the stack view vertically.

Comment: may be as your image the label left to the image

Comment: I just came across the same problem: My StackView was set to a fixed height of 300pts (with "Fill Equally") but this and also every try to give the it the same width/height as the great-grandparent View (my layout: Base View -> Great-Grandparent View -> Button View & Grandparent View -> ScrollView -> StackView) kept the ScrollView from being actually scrollable. Pickers are usually pretty wide, so if you've got one in your StackView (even inside a View), setting leading,... to 0 won't make it smaller, only "StackView.width = GrandparentView.width" will (but also disables horizontal scrolling).